# Chromebook Hardware - Is a Motherboard Upgrade at all a possibility?

Tags: upgrade, chromebook

I have an ASUS Chromebook C202SA-YS02-GR (Chrome OS replaced with BIOS from MrChromebox.Tech and Linux Mint). The hardware specifications are garbage and barely run anything. Is it possible to either hardmod new RAM/memory/processor or upgrade the motherboard?

EDIT: Here is the output of Neofetch:

[image: Neofetch output screenshot]

EDIT: I am looking for a better Intel Processor (i5, 3.0 GHz??), 8GB of RAM, 32+ GB memory (PCIe)

Comment: It might be possible to change the RAM, it uses DDR3L memory but it could be soldered to the motherboard. Nothing else in that model is replaceable. The CPU & Graphics are soldered to the board, the board itself is custom to that notebook line so can only be replaced with another motherboard from the same model.